# Vue useStorage (usevue) always starting clean rather than importing state in Pinia store

Tags: vue.js, local-storage, vuejs3, pinia, vueuse

I built my app on top of `vitesse-nuxt3`, and all is going well except for trying to use LocalStorage via `vueuse`.

**Component:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const { test } = useTestStore()
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ test }}</pre>
    <hr>
    <input
      :id="slug"
      v-model="value"
      type="text"
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

**Pinia Store:**

```
import { acceptHMRUpdate, defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core'

export const useTestStore = defineStore('test', () => {
  const test = ref(
    useStorage('test', {
      initials: 'It is initials',
    }),
  )

  return ({
    test,
  })
})

if (import.meta.hot)
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useTestStore, import.meta.hot))
```

I watch it set the data (in Chrome's dev tools), but it always reloads the default data instead rather than persisting between refreshes.

Thank you.

Comment: `useStorage` persists data correctly in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-use-storage?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Cheers. https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mgbef6-gfkpou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-mgbef6-gfkpou) is that the component is being rendered server-side, which has no Local Storage, so [`useStorage()` defaults to the given initial value](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/73cc5c2/packages/core/useStorage/index.ts#L142-L143).

One workaround is to render the component on the client only, using the [`<client-only>` component](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/components#clientonly-component):

```html
<client-only>
  <component-that-uses-local-storage />
</client-only>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vueuse-usestorage-nuxt3?file=pages%2Findex.vue)

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my issues perfectly. Really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

for store like this like @tony19 said

```js
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
    id: 'auth.store',
    state: () => {
        token: {
            accessToken: useStorage('accessToken', [XXXX], undefined, { serializer: StorageSerializers.object }),
            refreshToken: useStorage('refreshToken', [YYYY], undefined, { serializer: StorageSerializers.object })
        },
    },
})
```

`[XXXX]` `[YYYY]` is default value

after ssr `pinia.state.value` become to

```js
window.__INITIAL_SSR_CONTEXT__ = {
    state: {
        "auth.store": {
            "token":{
                "accessToken":[XXXX],
                "refreshToken":[YYYY]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on client side reasign the json object to store like this

```js
const ssr_state = (window as any)['__INITIAL_SSR_CONTEXT__']?.['state']
if (ssr_state) {
    pinia.state.value = ssr_state
}
```

so the `accessToken`, `refreshToken` property changes to plan object on client side, you can change it but the storage don't update.

my solution:

add one action to store

```
actions:{
    // ...
    // call this once when isSSR is true on client side entry
    reasignToken() {
      this.token = {
        accessToken: useStorage('accessToken', this.token.accessToken, undefined, {
          serializer: StorageSerializers.object
        }),
        refreshToken: useStorage('refreshToken', this.token.refreshToken, undefined, {
          serializer: StorageSerializers.object
        })
      }
    },
    // regular call on server side and client side
    setToken(token) {
        //... 
    }
}
```